# <tr> squeezed when <tbody> is display:block

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, page-break

I need to add a display block to my tbody in order to make my page-break-inside working.

When I do that, the page break works on printing, but the table's shape is modified for one specific tbody.

html:

```
<div class="row section-content">
   <table>
      <tbody class="subsection">
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Personal infos</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="check">
            <td class="control-title">Is licensed</td>
            <td class="check-body control-body">false</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="text">
            <td class="control-title">First name</td>
            <td class="text-body control-body"> Gc yt?tv</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="text">
            <td class="control-title">Last name</td>
            <td class="text-body control-body">Bhvug7y</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="text">
            <td class="control-title">Adress</td>
            <td class="text-body control-body">Guvyb</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="radioBtn">
            <td class="control-title">Wants to suscribe to monthly discount</td>
            <td class="radio-body control-body">No</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="number">
            <td class="control-title">Annual household income</td>
            <td class="number-body control-body">10</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody class="subsection">
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Accomodation</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="gps">
            <td class="control-title">Location</td>
            <td class="gps-body control-body">55.8755037, -4.2547716</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="number">
            <td class="control-title">Iso reference</td>
            <td class="number-body control-body">15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="radioBtn">
            <td class="control-title">Accomodation type</td>
            <td class="radio-body control-body">House</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**Before:**
[image]]

**After with display block:**
[image]

Comment: add styles as code snippet (button in edit post dialog) please

Comment: add css also to the code

Comment: That is expected. When the `tbody` is `display: block` the `tr` no longer has a parent that is `table-row-group` so an anonymous `table-row-group` has to be generated around it, and an anonymous `table` has to be generated around that. That anonymous table is then rendered according to the normal table rendering rules, so it shrink wraps the content (which is no longer connected to the real table element).

Comment: I m adding the CSS, longer than expected

Comment: Thx @Quentin, but is there a work arround ??

Comment: I can't add CSS, it needs bootstrap

Comment: @GuilhemFry FYI: you can add bootstrap by using simple CDN and `<link>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do had the same problem and after searching all over i found a solution for my problem which is, first add a class to table which you dont want to break while printing like `unbreakable` now add css

```
.unbreakable td{
    width: 100% !important;
}
.unbreakable tr{
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

It worked fine for me hope it works for you too... :) Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with the same issue for days, i found that using `display:table-row-group` works perfectly for this situation.

`display:block` will disconnect the element from the parent table, causing this issue.
`display:table-row-group` render the element just like a `<tbody>`, keeping the DOM correct.

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `display:table-row-group` will keep the DOM correct, but the scroll property doesn't work with it.

Is there any alternative to make a table scrollable as well as keep it unbreakable?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34602131)