# display: block squeezing table

Tags: html, css

I've created a table which holds some data, i was getting an error where my table was being squeezed when i added `display: block` to which i fixed by using a solution i found on stack-overflow which is [<tr> squeezed when <tbody> is display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937046/tr-squeezed-when-tbody-is-displayblock). This however gave me another display error which makes the first column on my table 100% width and leaves the others squeezed.

Any suggestions/help on how i would fix this would be appreciated.

How the table looks;

[image]

```css
    #requestContents tr{
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
    
    #requestContents td{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="requestContents" style="display: block; height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Request ID</th>
              <th>Request Type</th>
              <th>Blood Type</th>
              <th>Notice</th>
              <th>Request Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Dat</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Why do you set the width of your table cells to 100%?

Comment: why would you add `display: block` ??

Comment: @DavidLee `height: 250` does not set without `display: block`

Comment: @Olafant i did it according to the solution i had found.

Comment: The table has 3 classes. No one can help you if you don't show the css and keep talking about a solution that obviously doesn't work without explaining what's really going on there.

Comment: You might want to use table-layout: fixed as shown in https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: @Olafant The 3 classes that i have are from Bootstrap. The solution that i found and used is; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937046/tr-squeezed-when-tbody-is-displayblock. And the Css i put within the question is all the Css i have for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    #requestContents thead,#requestContents tbody{
        display:table; width:100%;

    }
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="requestContents" style="display: block; height: 90px; overflow-y: scroll">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="20%">Request ID</th>
              <th width="20%">Request Type</th>
              <th width="20%">Blood Type</th>
              <th width="20%">Notice</th>
              <th width="20%">Request Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Dat</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
              <td>Dummy Data</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Check this solution :)

Comment: Perfectly Done. Thank you.